# Extent Report Exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, report, extent

I am getting the following exception while using Extent Report.
Any clue how do I resolve this?
I have listed the dependencies from POM.XML that I have used

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/template/TemplateModelException
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:86)
 at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:375)
 at com.eshot.qa.utils.ExtentReporterNG.generateReport(ExtentReporterNG.java:29)
 at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1097)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.template.TemplateModelException
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I have the following dependencies in the POM.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.11.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the latest version, instead of version 2 which is no longer supported.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a link to the latest documentation: http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/

Comment: Thanks, I have upgraded to the latest versions and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have added freemarker and extentreports lib and still facing above error
```

then you should be followed below steps, it will be working fine
1) Delete only 'freemarker' folder from your local repository
i.e .m2\repository\org\freemarker\
2) And saved your pom.xml file again and run your code